# Trying to connect Postgresql remotely(windows OS)

Tags: windows, postgresql

New to PostgreSQL and running PostgreSQL on windows 
I have a PostgreSQL running locally on a remote machine and also a PostgreSQL on my laptop(win 10)(same LAN), trying to connect to the remote PostgreSQL from my laptop but getting the error 
no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xxx.x.xxx", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off

I can telnet the remote machine with port 5432 
telnet xxx.xxx.x.xxx 5432 is OK ,for testing purpose ,I have given all for the connection and also my PostgreSQL installation/configuration is default on my laptop and on the remote machine . Not sure how to dig the issue here, is there any issue of running services locally without specific ip is a problem?
when I run select(host(inet_server_add r())) my o/p is just ::1

My  pg_hba file is as below ,

```
#IPv4 local connections:
host    all        all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             all             md5 
#IPv6 local connections:
host    all      all             ::1/128                 md5
#Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: Try to add a line in pg_hba.conf of the remote machine with "host all all <IP address>/32 md5" - replace <IP address> with one *real* IPV4 address of the remote machine and "run pg_ctl reload" on the remote machine.

Comment: Ok..thanks will try it..but it seems to be a problem only my machine..could not telnet with port..